# How to select 1 random row from the latest 30 rows in MySql?

Tags: mysql

I want to select one row from the latest 30 rows based on the date.
And with the below it is selecting the random row from all the rows and thats not what I want.

```
SELECT * FROM product where userId=1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

So how can I select from the latest 30? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sub-select will return the last 30, and then you can choose a random row from there

```sql
SELECT pr.* FROM
    ( SELECT * from product 
      WHERE pr.userId=1
      ORDER BY created_at DESC
      LIMIT 30 ) AS pr
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: And please keep in mind that `ORDER BY RAND()` is a notorious performance antipattern. Keep that number of rows to consider low, like 30, and you'll be fine.